# Computer has video artifacts after been exposed to rain

Tags: hardware-failure

My desktop now displays video artifacts after been exposed to rain. Only a very small amount of moisture went inside the case. The only place I noticed any water was on the CPU socket. I used a hair dryer and paper towels to wick any remaining moisture. When I boot the PC it loads it the OS, but there are large numbers of video artifacts. The artifacts appear symmetric if that helps.

I am wondering what components I need to replace. I'd like to salvage what I can.

My setup: AMD Athlon x3, Asus main board (AM2 socket), nVidia GT 430 PCIe, 8gb (4gb x2) DDR3

Comment: What is your full set-up?  Do you have a dedicated video card, is it built into the mobo, or do you have an APU?  (Full specs aren't really necessary, just a summary of items like that).  Information like this would be helpful for others to diagnose.

Comment: Try installing a spare graphics card if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the issue is very close to the GPU. Remove power immediately and thoroughly dry the GPU, video memory, and anything near there. There's a good chance everything will be fine, but don't leave power applied to moist equipment -- it will corrode and do permanent damage. There is almost certainly still some moisture hiding between the GPU and the motherboard. Heating it from the back may help, but you can probably do it from the sides.